# TypeScript: Replace object property type

Tags: typescript

When I merge two objects with an arbitrary count of keys and the types of a property gets overwritten in that merge. How can I express this in typescript?

```
const a: {[propName: string]: string | number | boolean} = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2, 
  c: true
}

const b: {[propName: string]: string } = {
  c: "2"
}

const c: {[propName: string]: string | number } = { ...a, ...b };
```

This example shows the typescript error, even if the type signature of c is correct.

Comment: Do you have a typo? Should it include the boolean, like: `const c: {[propName: string]: string | number | boolean }`?

Comment: @FrankModica I belive it's not a typo, his reasoning is that `c` gets overwritten to it does not matter it is `bool` in `a`

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly type the variables as being indexable by a `string` as you do for `a` and `b`, Typescript will not track the keys that you assign in the object literal (after all they don't matter, the object is indexable by any string) so it has no way to know that the property will be overwritten in the spread.

If you let the compiler infer the types for `a` and `b` all will work as expected:

```
const a = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2, 
  c: true
}

const b = {
  c: "2"
}

const c: {[propName: string]: string | number } = { ...a, ...b }; // ok now since the compiler knows that `c` in `a` will be overwritten
```

If you want to define object literals that are constrained by another type (for example here, they are constrained by the index signature) but you also want to preserver the actual type of the object literal, you can use a function to achieve this:

```
function constrain<T>() {
    return function <U extends T>(o: U) {
        return o
    }
}
const a = constrain<{ [propName: string]: string | number| boolean }>()({
    a: 1,
    b: 2, 
    c: true
})

const b = constrain<{ [propName: string]: string  }>()({
    c: "2"
})

const c: {[propName: string]: string | number } = { ...a, ...b };
```

Comment: Is there really this function needed?

Comment: @danieldergrosse if you want to get inference for from the object literal and constrain it to somethin then yes. But not specifying any type works as well ..

Answer (score -1):

If you need merge an object in typescript, you can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#merge)

```
var object = {
  'a': [{ 'b': 2 }, { 'd': 4 }]
};

var other = {
  'a': [{ 'c': 3 }, { 'e': 5 }]
};

_.merge(object, other);

// Output:
// { 'a': [{ 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }, { 'd': 4, 'e': 5 }] }
```